# cell properties returned nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewCell named `GateCell`, inside it I placed one label and one text field. 
In `GateCell.h`

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *gateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *gateTextField;
```

In `GateTableViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tableView registerClass:[GateCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
}
```

Finally at cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I used like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    GateCell *cell = (GateCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    cell.gateLabel.text = @"Gate";
    cell.gateTextField.text = @"Open Gate"
    return cell;
}
```

When I print the description of the cell, I getting the following..

```
<`GateCell`: 0x7b6bd790; baseClass = `UITableViewCell`; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b6c2e60>> <br>
```

Printing description of cell->_gateLabel:

> nil

Printing description of cell->_gateTextField:

> nil

Why label and textField returns nil when cell is created ???

Comment: Please learn to format the code that you add to your question

Comment: Are you assuming that because you've declared the properties they are allocated when the object is allocated?

Comment: Please format your code first

Comment: Are you sure you connected IBOutlet properties with the views in your storyboard/nib?

Comment: Sorry Guys, I'll try to improve code formatting soon..

Comment: @hasan83 yes.. I connected..

Comment: add GateCell.m code. if you didn't solve the problem already

Comment: dod you have a nib file or storyboard?

Comment: @hasan83 I didn't code anything there...

Comment: I have only StoryBoard file

Comment: @trojanfoe isn't so ??? if not, can u explain it

Comment: Did you fix your problem ?

Comment: @Niko Yes i fixed the problem. The problem was using two storyBoards. I had this `GateTableViewController` controller in 2nd storyBoard. I have not mentioned the storyBoard name when i'm calling this cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously encountered troubles when doing `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and doing a `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I had to replace `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and directly init cells since `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` had been made.

Try in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` this way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Create your custom cell GateCell the way it has to be done providing the 'reuseIdentifier'
    //With a standard UITableViewCell it should be :
    //UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    GateCell *cell = [[GateCell alloc] init];

    cell.gateLabel.text = @"Gate";
    cell.gateTextField.text = @"Open Gate"
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing ensure that you connected the `IBOutlet` from the interface builder. if not then connect the `IBOutlet`.
for getting a cell use the following

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellReuseIdentifier"];
```

Comment: I have connected the IBOutlet. Then also it is returning nil.

Comment: could you plz explain how did you connect the IBOutlets?

Comment: Drag and Drop.. From GateCell in GateTableViewController(StoryBoard) to GateCell.h file

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource for the table?

Comment: Yes everything is done. If I do cell.textlabel.text = @"HI"; The cell is returning with HI.. If I use label which I created, its returning nil

Answer (score -1):

By calling

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[GateCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

the table view will create a cell directly, not from a NIB file, so your `IBOutlets` won't be set (there is nowhere they could be set from).

Either you should be registering a NIB instead of a class or you should be creating the subviews as part of `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.

Your additional comments say that you're using a storyboard. In this case you should be setting the class of the cell you add in storyboard to `GateCell` and setting the cell identifier to `cellIdentifier`. Then, in code, you should remove the call to `[self.tableView registerClass:[GateCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];` because making that call is replacing the storyboard registration...